# Cells with different images based on their types: UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to set different images on cells based on their types. Each section has different types of cells. At least two types, like there are seats in seat map so legends are available seats, booked, disabled seat and selected seat. What i am not getting is how to identify cells and assign them images accordingly. I am getting total seats plus disabled seats. Here disabled seats are for example i have 20 total seats and in a row i am showing 9 seats so there will be three rows generated having 9,9 and 2 seats, i have completed it to 27 so that all three rows get filled with seats, those 7 extra seats are disabled seats. How can i manage these now. Feel free to ask if anything not clear.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"vals count:%d", [arrSeats count]);
for(int i=0; i<[arrLevels count]; i++)
{
    if(section == i)
    {
        int v;
        NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTot objectAtIndex:i]];
        v = [cnt intValue];
        if(v<=9)
        {
            return 9;
        }
        else{
       int numOfRow = v/9; //2
        if(v % 9 > 0)
            numOfRow +=1;  //2+1 = 3
       int c = numOfRow*9;
        return c;
        } 
    }
}
return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

int v;
NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTot objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
v = [cnt intValue];
if(v < 9)
{
    if(cell.selected){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]];  // highlight selection
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]]; // Default color
    }
}else{
    int numOfRow = v/9; //2
    if(v % 9 > 0)
        numOfRow +=1;  //2+1 = 3
    int c = numOfRow*9;
    int get = c-v;
    for(int i=0; i<get; i++)
    {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_seat.png"]];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UIColoectionView we get indexPath which gives section and item number of cell. So check indexPath.row. If less then 20 check cell.selected. If greater then 20 they are blank. I wrote some code. Please check correct logic

```
int v;
NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTot objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
v = [cnt intValue];  
if(indexPath.row < v)
{


if(v < 9)
{
    if(cell.selected){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]];  // highlight selection
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]]; // Default color
    }
}

}
else
{
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_seat.png"]];

}
```